# Pandas - Add columns to dataframe which finds the sum and mean of item sales by item id in the previous month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe named grouped_train which lists the number of sales of each item in each store by month. Here's an example of the dataframe.

| date_block_num | item_id | shop_id | item_cnt_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 32 | 0 | 6 |
| 0 | 32 | 5 | 1 |
| 0 | 26 | 1 | 3 |
| 0 | 26 | 18 | 9 |
| 1 | 32 | 46 | 1 |
| 1 | 26 | 50 | 2 |

There are 33 date_block_nums which correspond to different months. I'd like to add two columns which list the sum of all sales by item_id in the previous month/date_block_num as well as the mean of sales for that particular item_id from all store_ids in the previous month, any rows where date_block_num == 0 should be None.

So, using the example df above, the output would look like:

| date_block_num | item_id | shop_id | item_cnt_month | item_sales_prev_month | mean_item_sales_prev_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 32 | 0 | 6 | None | None |
| 0 | 32 | 5 | 1 | None | None |
| 0 | 26 | 1 | 3 | None | None |
| 0 | 26 | 18 | 9 | None | None |
| 1 | 32 | 46 | 1 | 7 | 3.5 |
| 1 | 26 | 50 | 2 | 12 | 6 |

I've written some code for just the sum_item_prev_month column which I believe works and could easily change it to create the mean sales column as well, but with over 2.9 million rows in my dataframe, my code takes multiple hours to run. Admittedly, I'm not well versed with pandas, there has to be some vectorized formula I'm missing to speed up this computation. Here's the code I have so far.

```
sales_by_item_by_month = grouped_train.groupby(['date_block_num', 'item_id'], as_index=False).agg({'item_cnt_month' : 'sum'})

date_block_nums = list(grouped_train['date_block_num'])
item_ids = list(grouped_train['item_id'])

sales_for_item_prev_month = []

for index in range(len(item_ids)):
    if date_block_nums[index] == 0:
        sales_for_item_prev_month.append(None)
    else:
        sales = sales_by_item_by_month[(sales_by_item_by_month['item_id'] == item_ids[index]) & (sales_by_item_by_month['date_block_num'] == date_block_nums[index] - 1)]
        
        if len(sales) == 0:
            sales_for_item_prev_month.append(0)
        else:
            sales_for_item_prev_month.append(int(sales['item_cnt_month'].values))
        
grouped_train['item_sales_prev_month'] = sales_for_item_prev_month
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `date_block_num` are sequential.

Try calculating the sum and mean using [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) then increment the `date_block_num` by 1 to align it to the next group:

```
sum_means = df.groupby(['date_block_num', 'item_id']).agg(
    item_sales_prev_month=('item_cnt_month', 'sum'),
    mean_item_sales_prev_month=('item_cnt_month', 'mean')
).reset_index()
sum_means['date_block_num'] += 1
```

`sum_means`:

```
   date_block_num  item_id  item_sales_prev_month  mean_item_sales_prev_month
0               1       26                     12                         6.0
1               1       32                      7                         3.5
2               2       26                      2                         2.0
3               2       32                      1                         1.0
```

Then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) back to the original frame:

```
df = df.merge(sum_means, on=['date_block_num', 'item_id'], how='left')
```

`df`:

```
   date_block_num  item_id  shop_id  item_cnt_month  item_sales_prev_month  mean_item_sales_prev_month
0               0       32        0               6                    NaN                         NaN
1               0       32        5               1                    NaN                         NaN
2               0       26        1               3                    NaN                         NaN
3               0       26       18               9                    NaN                         NaN
4               1       32       46               1                    7.0                         3.5
5               1       26       50               2                   12.0                         6.0
```

---

Complete Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date_block_num': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 1},
    'item_id': {0: 32, 1: 32, 2: 26, 3: 26, 4: 32, 5: 26},
    'shop_id': {0: 0, 1: 5, 2: 1, 3: 18, 4: 46, 5: 50},
    'item_cnt_month': {0: 6, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 9, 4: 1, 5: 2}
})

sum_means = df.groupby(['date_block_num', 'item_id']).agg(
    item_sales_prev_month=('item_cnt_month', 'sum'),
    mean_item_sales_prev_month=('item_cnt_month', 'mean')
).reset_index()
sum_means['date_block_num'] += 1

df = df.merge(sum_means, on=['date_block_num', 'item_id'], how='left')
```